# What is $(g \circ f)(3)$?

Tags: functions

If $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = \sqrt{x+4}$

What is $g \circ f (3)$ ?

$g(f(x))$ would be $(\sqrt{x^2+4})(3)$ correct?

What would be my next move in figuring this out?

Comment: First evaluate $f(3)=z$ then plug the result into $g$, then you get the result $(g \circ f)(3)=g(z)$...

Comment: @SenzuBean : $(\sqrt{x^2+4})(3)$ is really, really bad notation, at least for math (maybe in some computer languages people would write that).  No math person would write that.  A popular alternative that conveys what you mean is $\sqrt{x^2+4} \Big|_{x=3}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

suppose $f(x)=x^2=X$, $(g\circ f)(x)= g(f(x))=g(X)=\sqrt{X+4}=\sqrt{x^2+4}\Rightarrow (g\circ f)(3)=\sqrt{3^2+4}$

Comment: appreciate that. It's coming back to me now.